# VBA - Finding folder inside a directory and returning the path of that folder

Tags: vba, excel

I am using excel vba to make an application that acts as a job card. User will fill in relevant fields, press a button to update a running summary of costs, as well as generate a printable pdf of the job card. I have very limited experience in coding (a semester of java 4 years ago) so i am relatively new to this.

Currently, the application automatically updates the summary file and can open a word template file and fill it in with information from the input fields, so it mostly works. I have realised an issue in the way it is finding the summary files, in that as soon as a folder name does not align with the way i am constructing the folder paths in the app, it will return errors.

At the moment I am going into folders like this:

```
    templatePath = "C:\SERVICE\Card Template.doc"
If cbxType.Text = "Plant" Then
    savePath = "C:\SERVICE\0.1 PLANT\" & cbxNo.Text & " - " & txtMakeModel.Text & " " & txtRego.Text & "\0.2 SERVICE SHEETS\"
    ElseIf cbxType.Text = "Vehicle" Then
    savePath = "C:\SERVICE\0.2 VEHICLES\"

End If
```

The directory is constructed from text and combo boxes which are populated once the user chooses a type (plant, vehicle, etc.) and then ID, which fills in boxes for model name, registration number, hours etc.

I am after a piece of code that can iterate through a given directory, searching the folder names for a string and returning the path of that folder. Each folder begins with the ID number, so I figure I can search folder names for that but I am not sure how to construct the loop. Any help with this, or alternative ideas would be appreciated. If it isn't too much to ask I'd also like a little bit of an explanation on how it works.

Comment: use the object ***FileSystemObject***

Comment: I just answer a Recursive FIle search problem, [VBA Verify File extension as excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053474/vba-verify-file-extension-as-excel-file/46054222#46054222), that can be modified for a folder search.