# Merge Worksheets from multiple Workbooks and adding a new column with worksheet title in all cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am totally new to VBA and trying to create a marcro that creates a new Excel file out of multiple worksheets and multiple Excel files. Basically I am opening 2 files saved in a specific folder, adding a new column to all Woksheets with a specific title in A1 + the ws name in all cells as long as there is data in column B. Then I am copying them over to a new file, unless of one specific worksheet. Afterwards I copy all sheets to one new sheet and deleting all others as they are no more needed. The code is working, but I am getting an empty line with description "Sheet 1" in "A2". Can anywone help me getting rid of this empty line?

Here the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Worksheets()

Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fol As Scripting.Folder
Dim f As Scripting.File
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim CombinedFile As Workbook

Set CombinedFile = Workbooks.Add

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fol = fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Folder")
    For Each f In fol.Files
    Debug.Print f.Path
          
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
        For Each WS In wb.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> "Sheet" Then
        
        Debug.Print WS.Name
        WS.Copy After:=CombinedFile.Worksheets(1)
        End If
        Next WS
        
        wb.Close
           
Next f

 Dim LASTROW As Long
 For Each WS In Sheets
    With WS
        LASTROW = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Columns(1).Insert
        .Range("A1") = "Sales Org"
        .Range("A2:A" & LASTROW) = WS.Name
    End With
Next WS


Dim i As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(i).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1000000").End(xlUp)(2)
Next i
Sheets(1).Activate


Dim sht As Object
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sht.Index <> 1 Then
        sht.Delete
    End If
Next

CombinedFile.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Folder1 " & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy hhmmss")
CombinedFile.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer:
you're adding all the sheets after the `Worksheets(1)`
but in the following statement, you'll have to specify a bit more

```
For Each WS In Sheets

    With WS
        LASTROW = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Columns(1).Insert
        .Range("A1") = "Sales Org"
        If Not CombinedFile.Sheets(1).Name = WS.Name Then
            .Range("A2:A" & LASTROW) = WS.Name
        End If
    End With
Next WS
```

(or use your later `.index` check when you're deleting the unneeded sheets)

That should prevent your empty row

The somewhat longer answer: the above + try to avoid using select and indent your code for readability. You also seem to have forgotten to set `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` at the end

**EDIT**
To give an example how your code can be indented/avoid Select(ion):

```
Sub Copy_Worksheets()

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fol As Scripting.Folder
    Dim f As Scripting.File
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim CombinedFile As Workbook
    

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set CombinedFile = Workbooks.Add
    
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fol = fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Folder")
    For Each f In fol.Files
        Debug.Print f.Path
        'are you sure all the files in the folder are workbooks?
        
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
        For Each WS In wb.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> "Sheet" Then
        
        Debug.Print WS.Name
        WS.Copy After:=CombinedFile.Worksheets(1)
        End If
        Next WS
        
        wb.Close
    Next f
    
    Dim LASTROW As Long
    For Each WS In Sheets
       With WS
           LASTROW = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           .Columns(1).Insert
           .Range("A1") = "Sales Org"
           If Not CombinedFile.Sheets(1).Name = WS.Name Then
               .Range("A2:A" & LASTROW) = WS.Name
           End If
       End With
    Next WS
    
    Dim i As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    CombinedFile.Sheets(2).Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=CombinedFile.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
        With Sheets(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        End With
    Next i
    
    For Each WS In CombinedFile.Worksheets
        If WS.index <> 1 Then
            WS.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    CombinedFile.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Folder1 " & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy hhmmss")
    CombinedFile.Close

End Sub
```

Let me know if something is unclear or doesn't work :)

PS: It's quite a good sub for a beginner, I must say.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved the issue. Not sure about the hint to avoid select and indent, but I will for sure understand once I learned a bit more about VBA. Still in a very early stage of understading.

Comment: Np, I made an edit on how it could look like. Good job on the code and happy exploring!

Comment: Ok, will test that latest change out. I assume the Application.DisplaAlerts and Application.ScreenUpdating is turning off and on the visualization of what Excel is doing when running throug the code. Never run through this sting before. I am really new to VBA, just good in using google and mappinog together solutions of other users. It took me some time, but at least it worked out in some way.

Comment: Regarding the Folder I am getting the workbooks from: Yes, I only have workbooks in it. I first run only through xlsx files, but noticed that is not working when the extensions is "XLSX". I never understood how to run both through xlsx and XLSX, so I just managed to not save any other file in the folder.

Comment: Ok, I´ve tested your code now. Works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: About the xlsx vs xls, you can check if the file is [Like *xls*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46054222/19353309) and you're welcome :)